# error: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, ternary-tree

I am stumped at this step while implementing a ternary tree:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct tnode *Tptr;
    typedef struct node
{
    char splitchar;
    Tptr lokid,eqkid,hikid;

}Tnode;

int research(Tptr p,char *s)
{
    if (!p) return 0;
    if (*s<p->
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

When I move the mouse icon near the `p`, it shows me a red color and error:

```
pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
```

My question is exactly what is an incomplete class? Please help me, thanks.

Comment: You forgot to define `struct tnode`. Also, are you sure you have a C compiler?

Comment: i  have visual  c+ 2010 and as i know,it supports  c as well

Comment: C+? If you mean Visual C++, that isn't a real C compiler. You might still be able to hack something up, but I'm just saying that a true C answer won't help you with that compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've typedef'd `Tptr` as a `struct tnode *`, but `tnode` is  not defined or even declared.  Perhaps you meant to name your `node` struct `tnode` instead?

BTW, there's an easy way to keep that from happening in the future...

```
typedef struct tnode {
    ...
} Tnode, *Tptr;
```

At that point, `Tptr` is always an alias to the correct type, even if you change `tnode`'s name to something else.

Comment: Another idea would be to not use pointer typedefs at all, then there is no chance of messing them up

Answer (score 1):

incomplete class (or type) is the type that is forward declared, but is not defined. Just like your `tnode`.
Probably you should replace `node` by `tnode` as the tag of structure in your example to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

"incomplete class type" suggests that your compiler believes this is C++ code rather than C code, since C does not have classes.

Note that line 5 makes `Tptr` a name for `struct tnode *`—pointer to a struct named "tnode", not "node" but "tnode", lowercase t, node.  Line 6 starts a typedef, then starts defining a struct named "node", no "t", just "node".  Line 11 finishes off the definition of "struct node", and then supplies a name for the earlier typedef: "Tnode", uppercase T, node.

You have four different names here now: Tptr, Tnode, tnode, and node.  The one with a lowercase "t" has never been "completed", so it's an "incomplete type" (but not class, because C does not have classes).